# Can you pass a model with RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using mvc 2 release candidate, and am wondering if there's any way to pass a model to an action using RedirectToAction.

For example, I have an edit action which takes an ID, and loads the record from a database, displays the current values in text boxes and lets the user edit and click submit:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
```

Then I have an edit action for the HttpPost which takes a model and updates the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Administration.Models.ManagementCompanyModel model)
```

Because I already have the model containing the new data, I don't want to simply re-direct to the Details action, I want to somehow redirect to the details action and pass the model.  Possible?

Comment: I didn't see there was an overloaded Method for View that takes the action name and an object for the model.   
return View("Details",mymodel);

Comment: that would be incorrect from a SEO point of view, and POST redirect GET is there for a reason as well

Answer (score 17):

```
TempData["Model"] = YourModel;
Return RedirectToAction("details");
```

and in details action, check for `TempData["Model"] != null`
and grab it from there