# Redirect MVC to action with custom object?

Tags: model-view-controller, redirect, edit

As indicated (by another poster) here: [Can you pass a model with RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959945/can-you-pass-a-model-with-redirecttoaction)

I would like to redirect my MVC 1 action to another action which normally would be the response called by an Edit page being posted back.

Can someone tell me how to do this please as all the suggestions I've seen so far have not worked.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of answers [here](http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/04/06/aspnet-mvc-pass-parameters-when-redirecting-from-one-action-to-another/) or [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg) (see 13. Use PRG Pattern for Data Modification)

The same answer was accepted a couple of [days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574170/prg-in-asp-net-mvc-but-with-object-data-transferred-to-the-redirected-action/2574201#2574201).